# Take notes and organize tasks by project, prioritiy, and urgency

Tags: project-management, note-taking, time-management, knowledge-organization

## Project organization

I'm looking for a note taking and organizer/task management application.

### What I'm using it for

I'm a freelance web developer and I have many projects at any given time, and each project has different tasks. Some of these tasks are important and need to be done right away. Some are less important and can wait a while. I'm looking for something to organize the data.

### Criteria

- Different sections for each project, with the ability to quickly switch between them.
- Quickly jot down notes and general information.
- Ability to store data for each project *securely*, such as login information, etc.
- Ability to organize tasks and sort by different fields such as priority, urgency, etc.
- Keep track of completed tasks.
- Not crucial, but it would be nice to have some kind of indicator if a task is coming close to a deadline.
- Absolutely has to run in a Linux environment if a desktop application. Web-based is preferable though.
- I don't need any kind of collaboration, this is for my own personal use.

## What I've tried

- **[Evernote](https://evernote.com/)**

  It's okay software, but it doesn't work on Linux. The Linux [clones](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/), and [client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nevernote/) available for it have a terrible interface, and I still can't sort things by priority.
- **[KeepNote](http://keepnote.org/)**

  I liked the directory structure it has, but it's also very difficult to organize tasks by priority. It's phenomenal for general note taking in a class environment though.
- **[Tomboy](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy)**

  This is what I'm using right now. It's nice because I can keep important notes in front of me so that I don't forget about them, but once you have too many notes it becomes a hassle to organize them.
- **[OneNote](https://www.onenote.com/)**

  As much as it pains me to say this, Microsoft did a great job on this one. It doesn't work on Linux. When running it through [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), it doesn't seem to work for me.
- Others

  Basically, nothing I've found has allowed me to sort things by priority, keep notes, and mark tasks as complete.

## Budget

I would prefer some [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software), but I'm definitely willing to pay for something that works well.

I don't want to spend more than $100 (I *will* if it's something amazing though), and I absolutely will not do something subscription based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [Quire](https://quire.io)? It can:

- create tasks within your projects easily,
- has quite a nice UI for noting things down,
- you need to create an account to use it, so password protected,
- can assign priority and filter tasks according to priority as well,
- list completed tasks,
- add tags,
- schedule tasks,
- is web based,
- it is free (but if it ever changes, you can export your projects),
- can integrate with GitHub and Calendars,
- seems generally quite nice.

Otherwise, I would have thought that something like [ToDoList](http://abstractspoon.weebly.com/) would be perfect for you, if only it was available on Linux. Or maybe [Task Coach](http://taskcoach.org/) (which is Open Source but is meant for desktop use) but I don't find it 100% practical in terms of quickly jotting down notes. However, it is probably just a matter of taste.

But maybe either of them is worth a look.

Comment: This is great. Although it's been 2 years since I asked this question, your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try Monday as well. I am using their service and it works great for me. I don't need to use any other tool to plan my projects and schedule. You can also share it with your clients. Also you can try this new freelancing platform [perfectlancer.com](https://perfectlancer.com). Its platform is supposed to be fully optimized and integrated with a built in organizer app